# Knowledge - Create Article only shows Name and Summary

Tags: profile, knowledge, articles

I am trying to set up SF Knowledge in my Org, but when I try to add an Article,  the editor only shows title and summary. 
I cant find a way to add the article itself.

What I am missing ? 
I have the System Administrator Profile with all the knowlege priviledges.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Custom Fields to Article Types

Create custom fields to store information that is important to your articles. The only standard
fields provided on article types are: Article Number, Summary, Title, and URL Name. **At minimum,
you want to create a field where authors can write the body of the article**.